# Coq Record Types

Tags: record, coq

I am new to Coq. I get an error when I try to define two record types that have type fields with the same name. For example:

```
Record squag := {
    U : Type;
    op : U -> U -> U where "x * y" := (op x y);
    idempotent_op : forall x : U, (x * x) = (x);
    commutative_op : forall x y : U, (x * y) = (y * x);
    antiAbsorbent_op : forall x y: U, (x * (x * y)) = (y)
}.
Record dummy := { 
    U : Type; 
    zero : U
}.
```

The error I get is:

> Error: U already exists.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot reuse record names in a Coq namespace. What you can do, however, is to declare the two records in separate files or modules:

```
Module Squag.
Record squag := {
    U : Type;
    op : U -> U -> U where "x * y" := (op x y);
    idempotent_op : forall x : U, (x * x) = (x);
    commutative_op : forall x y : U, (x * y) = (y * x);
    antiAbsorbent_op : forall x y: U, (x * (x * y)) = (y)
}.
End Squag.

Module Dummy.
Record dummy := { 
    U : Type; 
    zero : U
}.
End Dummy.
```

Then, you can refer to the two fields separately as `Squag.U` and `Dummy.U`.

Comment: What if what I am defining is a library of some algebraic theories (monoids, groups, ..)? Is there a better way to handle this other than having a seperate module for each?

Comment: @ymmagdi You might want to look at [Packaging Mathematical Structures](https://hal.inria.fr/inria-00368403v1/document) paper (it's about [math-comp](https://github.com/math-comp/math-comp)) and [math-classes](https://math-classes.github.io) library (there is a paper describing its architecture).

Comment: Declaring separate names for similar structures is a minor nuisance compared to the issue of proving and using common lemmas about these structures -- e.g. if I prove something about groups, can I use it for abelian groups? The libraries Anton mentioned tackle this issue, and you should have a look there.